# Computed property or other way to change style depending on value inside v-for in Vue

Tags: vue.js, v-for, computed-properties

I have component like this:

```
Vue.component('mcp-item', {
    template: '#mcp-item-template',
    data() {
        return {
            name: "MCP v2",
            version: "2.0",
            imei: 'XXXXXX XX XXXXXX X',
            relays: [
                { name : "REL1", state : 0 },
                { name : "REL2", state : 0 }
            ],
            inputs: [
                { name: "BP1", state: 0, color: "#CC0000" },
                { name: "BP2", state: 0, color: "#CC0000"  },
                { name: "BP3", state: 1, color: "#00CC00"  },
                { name: "BP4", state: 0, color: "#CC0000"  },
                { name: "BP5", state: 0, color: "#CC0000"  },
                { name: "BP6", state: 0, color: "#CC0000"  }
            ],
        }
    },
    methods: {
        reboot: function (event) { alert( this.imei) }
    }
})
```

And somewhere in compoment template:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Input</th>
            <th>State</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody v-for="input in inputs" :key="input.name">
        <tr>
            <td :style="{ 'color': input.color}">{{input.name}}</td>
            <td>{{input.state}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

As you can see, now I have dedicated `color` field in my object (which is element of `inputs` array in `data`):

JS:

```
{ name: "BP1", state: 0, color: "#CC0000" }
```

HTML:

```
<td :style="{ 'color': input.color}">{{input.name}}</td>
```

**I want to get rid of this extra property, but I can't figure out how can I use computed property inside of v-for loop to make red color for state==0 and green for state==1**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than creating a computed property or adding the logic into the template, I would create a method `getColor(state)` which looks like this:

```
getColor(state) {
  let color = '';
  if (state === 0) {
    color = 'red';
  } else if (state === 1) {
    color = 'green';
  }
  return { color };
}
```

Or if the only values are `0` and `1` you could shorten this to something like:

```
getColor(state) {
  const color = state === 0 ? 'red' : 'green';
  return { color };
}
```

then call it like this:

`<td :style="getColor(input.state)">{{input.name}}</td>`

Comment: Where experienced Vue user would put that method? In the global scope, or in the component?

Comment: If you are only using it in this component, add it there. If you think you will use it in multiple components, you could create an external "helpers" file which exports this method and import it as needed.

Comment: personally i would return "color: red" from the method. Seems to behave strangely if you pass it an object.

Answer (score 1):

maybe computed property is an overkill - what about simple condition:

```
<td :style="{ 'red': input.state === 0, 'green': input.state === 1}">...// </td>
```

Comment: Thanks for very clean and minimal solution, but I choosen the other one because I can set more CSS properties.